# How to know which two hyperparameters are more important in SVM, KNN and MLP?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, nonparametric, scikit-learn

I am trying to limit myself to a maximum two hyper-parameters that are important in `KNN`, `SVM` and `MLP` classifiers. How should I know which hyper-parameters have more effects than the other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot easily do that in `MLP`. Among the most important hyper-parameters, there is number of layers, and even if you set it there is number of neurons parameter in each of these layers.

In `SVM`, you might want to try different `kernels` and their associated parameters. For example, `gamma`, `C`, and `degree` are among important ones.

In my opinion, in `KNN`, you should first play with `K` and a suitable `metric` choice (cosine, euclidean etc.).

Comment: Ah, thank you! Just one more question, how can I do a grid seach in python without really importing that module? First, I want to choose the most important parameters in `KNN`, `SVM` and `MLP` and then I have to find the optimal values for them. I know I can do it with `import GridSearchCv ` but the thing is I want to learn how to implement the `GridSearchCv` using `python` itself. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: You can implement a grid search of any kind via simple loops.  For CV, create validation sets via random index generation and use the same validation sets for all of your combinations.